# OOD issue using composition

Tags: oop

I have a class as below :

```
public UIManager{

    private UIInstructor uiInstructor;
    private MOdel model;


}
```

UIManager delegates some of his tasks to UIInstructor.

My question is :  If UIInstructor wants to use some instance variables of UIManager (e.g: Model object), is it a 
good design practise to have "UIInstructor" store refernce to UIManager ?

Or do we need to chnage the design such that "UIInstructor" should not "depend" on UIManager for any of its operations ?

Answer (score 0):

Added a reference in UIInstructor to UImanager will create a cyclic dependency, which is not good.

Ideally the fields that constitute to make a new class should not depends on this new class.

Hence chnage the design such that "UIInstructor" should not "depend" on UIManager for any of its operations.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the first solution to try is to have the `UIManager` object pass a reference to `model` to `uiInstructor`. In general it's a good idea to avoid dependencies you don't need, and cyclic dependencies in particular.

In the spirit of reducing dependencies, you might want to consider whether `uiInstructor` should really see *all* of `model`. So you might have your `Model` class as follows:

```
class Model
{
    private InstructorModel instructorModel;
    private StudentModel studentModel;
}
```

you can imagine we might add to your manager so it displayed  a student as well

```
class UIManager{
    private UIInstructor uiInstructor;
    private UIStudent uiStudent;
    private Model model;
}
```

then the `UIManager` passes `model.instructorModel` to initialize `uiInstructor`, typically via a constructor. And passes `model.studentModel` to initialize `uiStudent`.

These are just some ideas. There's a lot of different ways of doing things, but a good rule of thumb is to arrange that each class only "sees" what it needs to.